# Jquery TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'search'

Tags: jquery, backbone-events

I want make a page loaded run the 'search' function, but i get error message in self.search(event).
please make some help there, how can i page load call the search function?

```
directory.views.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

templateLoader: directory.utils.templateLoader,

initialize: function() {
    this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));
    this.render();
    var keyword = '_firstkey';
    $(document).ready(function (event) {
    self.search(event); //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'search'##

    })
},

render: function(eventName) {
    $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
    this.listView = new directory.views.EmployeeListView({el: $('.scroll', this.el), model: this.model});
    this.listView.render();
    return this;
},

events: {
    "keyup .search-key": "search"
},
 search: function(event) {
    var key = $('.search-key').val();
    this.model.findByName(key);
    return false;
},
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined a `self` variable inside the `initialize` method, you need to create a closure variable like `var self = this;`

```
directory.views.SearchPage = Backbone.View.extend({

    templateLoader: directory.utils.templateLoader,

    initialize: function() {
        this.template = _.template(this.templateLoader.get('search-page'));
        this.render();
        var keyword = '_firstkey';
        var self = this; //add self variable here
        $(document).ready(function (event) {
            self.search(event); //Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'search'##

        })
    },

    render: function(eventName) {
        $(this.el).html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        this.listView = new directory.views.EmployeeListView({el: $('.scroll', this.el), model: this.model});
        this.listView.render();
        return this;
    },

    events: {
        "keyup .search-key": "search"
    },
    search: function(event) {
        var key = $('.search-key').val();
        this.model.findByName(key);
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Might be useful to tell us why the error message is "no such method" rather than a ReferenceError or "undefined is not an object".

Comment: @muistooshort here the `self` seems to be pointing to the `window` (global object). In chrome at least `self` exists in the global space

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.self (this is why properly paranoid people don't use `self` for this purpose, `_this` and `that` are better choices)

Comment: @muistooshort I just searched for the same reference link!! thanks for posting it before me

Comment: @muistooshort thanks man... I'll correct it... also in this case I may prefer to use `$.proxy` to pass the context instead of closure variable. do you see any problem with that

Comment: I've been leaning `_.bind` in Backbone code but `$.proxy` is the same thing and you'll have both around in Backbone.

Comment: @muistooshort I haven't used backbone... using angularjs now... but my question was do you see any downside for this over using a closure variable

Comment: I think they're all pretty much the same: `_.bind`, `Function.bind`, `$.proxy`, `var _this = this`, ... I find that the binding approaches better express my intent whereas the `var _this = this` version looks like trickery.